# What's the difference between assignee and approver in gitlab merge request?

Tags: gitlab

It's quite confusing. Is 'assignee' the person who committed the code or the person who is responsible for finally merging after code review (probably due to permission issues.)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the GitLab's documentation:

> Choose an assignee to designate someone as the person responsible for the **first review of the merge request**.

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/getting_started.html#assignee)

So, answering to your question is the second option :-)